# How to concatenate reverse if statement to string?

Tags: string, perl, if-statement, concatenation

```
use DateTime::Format::Natural;
$parser = new DateTime::Format::Natural;
$dt = $parser->parse_datetime("1 Test 2010");
print "Date: " . ($dt->dmy('/') if $parser->success);
```

Why doesn't the last line compile?

Comment: Kindly accept an answer to close the question. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't compile because that form of `if` is a statement modifier; it can only be used at the end of a statement, not elsewhere in an expression.

You can do:

```
print "Date: " . ( $parser->success ? $dt->dmy('/') : '' );
```

or:

```
print "Date: " . do { $dt->dmy('/') if $parser->success };
```

(though the latter will try to print $parser->success if it is false, and it will print "Date: 0" in that case).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the ternary operator here?

```
print 'Date: ' . ($parser->success ? $dt->dmy('/') : '');
```

Or split the code into two statements;

```
print 'Date: ';
print $dt->dmy('/') if $parser->success;
```